# Swift: How many of the same object in array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a CollectionView with items like...

```
Fruit(name: String, price: Int, imageUrl: String)
```

The user can select multiple `Fruits` and then proceed to a "checkout" which is a `UITableView` with all the fruits selected. 
The `UITableViewCell` contains: `amountLabel`, `fruitLabel`, `priceLabel`.

I want to show how many of each fruit and the total price is, in this view.

What is the best way to do this?

What I see now :

```
Banana - 1$
Orange - 3$
Banana - 1$
Apple - 2$
Apple - 2$
Banana - 1$
Orange - 3$
Orange - 3$

total: 16$
```

What I want to see:

```
3x Banana - 3$
2x Apple - 4$
3x Orange - 9$

total: 16$
```

Comment: You should wrap your Fruit in an Order struct together with an int counter that you increase when the same fruit is added instead of storing a separate fruit. Then you could also have a calculated property in the Order struct that returns the total amount. The Order objects could be stored in a dictionary with the fruit or the fruit name as key

Comment: @JoakimDanielson he wants to do that with this data source. That is his question.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I posted this as a comment and not as an answer which is quite different so I think I am allowed to present an alternative route for OP to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the array and sum up the prices

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: fruits, by: {$0.name})
var total = 0
for (key, value) in grouped {
    let price = value.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.price})
    print(value.count, key, "\(price)$")
    total += price
}
print("total: \(total)$")
```

Comment: Ah yes, I knew there was a Swifty alternative to `NSCountedSet` but I couldn't remember what it was. This is a better answer than mine :)

Comment: This was a great answer. Sorry for the late reply but I was trying to populate the cells with the information given. 
I created a new class `FilteredFruits()` and a new array `[filteredFruits]()` and after the `print(value.count...` I also did `filteredFruits.append(Fruit(amount: value.count, name: key, price: price) ` and then populated the cells with `filteredFruits[indexPath.row].name` etc. 
Is this the right way to continue? thanks

Comment: If that's what you expect, yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for `NSCountedSet`.

[You can see the documentation for `NSCountedSet` here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscountedset)

You can create an `NSCountedSet` like...

```
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: fruits)
```

and then get info out of it like...

```
countedSet.objectEnumerator.forEach {
    let count = countedSet.count(for: $0)

    print($0.name, count, count * $0.price)
}
```

For your table view you can use `countedSet.objectEnumerator.allObjects.count` for the number of rows.

Comment: Can you use this as a data source for a table view?

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase. Can he use this to get the table view to show the result like how he wants easily? (His last part of the question)

Comment: I am asking if this would work as the **data source** for the table view to easily achieve his required result format?